# ASP.NET - Get SessionID while in from the Global.ASAX

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax, sessionid

I'm recording the session start times from when people log into my .NET 2.0 web application, but I'd also like to record the Session ID.  Can someone give me some example code on how to accomplish this (how to access the Session ID from within the Global.ASAX).

If you need any additional info just let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID

Edit to show null test:

```
if ((HttpContext.Current != null) && (HttpContext.Current.Session != null) {
  id = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
}
```

Comment: I would advise you to check this for null as well just to be safe.

Comment: "I would advise you to check this for null as well just to be safe"

Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer

Comment: When I try to check for Null (!= null), I get "null is not declared. Null constant is no longer supported. Use 'System.DBNull' instead

I'm programming in VB if that matters

Comment: In VB you would use Nothing instead of null. null is the C# keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can get at it quite simply with `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionId` as you probably already know. You need to be on or after `Application_AcquireRequestState` before the session state has been loaded, and session state is also only loaded when the requested resource implements `IRequiresSessionState`. You can see a list of all the events in global.asax here: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5771721.html and read more about `IRequiresSessionState` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Write to the session the datetime and sessionid at the moment of the first request following ASP.NET's identifying the user's session.

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
    var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
    if (session != null) {
        if (session["foo"] == null) {
            session["foo"] = DateTime.Now.Ticks + "|" + session.SessionID;
        }
    }
}
```